# Wordpress Query var duplicated in the url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress site that is duplicating query vars in the url, ie:

```
https://mysite.co.uk/?test=test?test=test?test=test?test=test
```

Wordpress version is 4.7.3.

The code to add the query var is

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'letter';
  return $vars;
}
```

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );

The code for generating the links that include the query var is

```
  function get_ispa_pagination() {
            $output = '';
            $letters= Array(
                'A,B,C',
                'D,E,F',
                'G,H,I',
                'J,K,L',
                'M,N,O',
                'P,Q,R',
                'S,T,U',
                'V,W,X',
                'Y,Z'
            );

            $output .= '<span class="epx-pagination">';
            $total = count($letters);
            $count = 1;

            foreach($letters as $letter) {
                $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url(add_query_arg('letter', $letter)) . '">'.$item.'</a>';
                if($count < $total) {
                    $output .= ' | ';
                }
                $count++;
            }
            $output .= '</span>';
            return $output;
    }
```

So far the soultions I have tried are:

Changing permalinks to default, which replicated the issue by adding

```
?page=9?page=9?page=9?page=9
```

the usual deactivating all plugins and using the default theme, but the issuse is still present.

Removing forcing SSL from the .htaccess file as this was the last thing added to the site before the issue appeared. This did not fix the problem.

I'm inclinded to think this problem is being caused by a .htaccess file or by the server rather than Wordpress. The .htaccess file contains

```
# BEGIN Force SSL
<IfModule rewrite_module>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END Force SSL

# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But with my limted knowlege of apache rewrite rules. I cannot see anything obvious that could lead to this error. Google and stackoverflow also have not shed any light on the issue only how to add and work with query vars within wordpress. Hopefully someone could help shed some light on the issue.